Conmutation of operators that act on many electrons
If I define the operator L as:
$$\vec{L}=\sum{\vec{l_i}}$$
where $\vec{l_i}$ is the operator of angular momentum of a single electron.
How can I justify formally that
$$\left[l_i ^2 , L^2\right]=0 $$ and that
$$\left[\sum{f(r_i)\vec{l_i}\cdot \vec{s_i}}, L^2\right] \neq 0 \quad ,$$
where $f(r_i)$ is a function of the distance of the electron $i$ to the system of reference?

Have you tried for one and two particles first?

recall that the operator $l_i$ is actually something of the form $1\otimes\ldots\otimes l_i \otimes \ldots 1$, meaning a tensor product operator which acts as the angular momentum operator on the $i$-th electron and as the identity on all other electrons, and that commutators are linear. That should at least take care of your first question.
